# internet explorer cannot open the internet site?

Tags: php, html

am getting this error when i open my site in internet explorer......... plz help me.

```
<?php



// no direct access

    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );



/* Definitions */

    define( 'BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );



    include_once (BASEPATH.'/layout_vars.php');

// Menu

    $document   = &JFactory::getDocument();

    $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer( 'module' );

    $module  = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_mainmenu' );

    $module->params = "showAllChildren=1";;

    $options = array( 'style' => "submenu");

    $mainmenu = $renderer->render( $module, $options );



?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

<head>
<meta name="verify-v1" content="pe1HKujmYcyuB76+2/OaoWO4qm/tBVq9vjgpGXB0KVE=" >

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/css/font_normal.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/css/fonts/<?php echo $this->params->get('fontVariation'); ?>.css" type="text/css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var menuSpeed = <?php echo $this->params->get('menuSpeed'); ?>;

    var mooStyle = '<?php echo $this->params->get('mooStyle'); ?>';         

</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/js/<?php echo $this->params->get('NavType'); ?>.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/css/menus/<?php echo $this->params->get('NavType'); ?>.css" type="text/css" />





<!--[if lte IE 7]>

<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>

<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.6a-min.js"></script>

<script>

DD_belatedPNG.fix('#wrapper'); /* EXAMPLE */

/* string argument can be any CSS selector */

/* using .png_bg example is unnecessary */

/* change it to what suits you! */

</script>

<![endif]--> 



<!-- Template Admin CSS Variables Defined --->



<style type="text/css">

body {font-size: <?=$this->params->get('fontSize');?>px;}

#content .contentheading {background:<?=$this->params->get('articleheader');?>; padding:3px 0 3px 0; vertical-align:middle;display:block; width: 100%;color: #fff;height:24px;line-height:24px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: -0.5px;}

.componentheading { background:<?=$this->params->get('componentheader');?>; color: #fff; padding:6px 6px 12px 6px;height:24px;line-height:28px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: -0.5px;margin-bottom: 8px;}

#topmenu li a{font-size:<?=$this->params->get('MainNavSize');?>px; color:<?=$this->params->get('NavColor');?>;}

#topmenu li:hover a, #topmenu li.sfhover a{color:<?=$this->params->get('NavHover');?>;}

#topmenu li ul li a, #topmenu li ul li:hover a {color:<?=$this->params->get('NavHover');?>;}   

a.mainlevel-top { font-size:<?=$this->params->get('TopNavSize');?>px; color:<?=$this->params->get('TopNavColor');?>;}

a.mainlevel-top:hover {color:<?=$this->params->get('TopNavHover');?>;}   

</style>

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/jxtc_escene/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php 

$Footermodcount=0;

if($this->countModules( 'user10 ')){

    $Footermodcount=$Footermodcount+1;

}

if($this->countModules( 'user11')){

    $Footermodcount=$Footermodcount+1;

}

if($this->countModules( 'user12')){

    $Footermodcount=$Footermodcount+1;

}

if($this->countModules( 'user13')){

    $Footermodcount=$Footermodcount+1;

}

if($this->countModules( 'user14')){

    $Footermodcount=$Footermodcount+1;

}

if ($Footermodcount == 0) {

    $Width=982;

}

else {

    $Width=(982-($Footermodcount*20))/$Footermodcount;

}

$UserWidth = $Width+20;

echo '<style type="text/css">

#footermods .moduletable{width:'.$Width.'px;}

#user10,#user11,#user12,#user13,#user14{width:'.$UserWidth.'px;}

</style>';

?>

</head>

<body class="bg_<?php echo $this->params->get('backgroundVariation'); ?>">



<!-- BEGIN IE6 WARNING -->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>

<style type="text/css"> 

#slitp {padding: 10px;border: 3px solid #000099;margin: 8px 0;background: #DFEFFF;color: #000;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 15px;}

#slitp h1 {padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-color: #000099;font-size: 16px;color: #000099;}

#slitp p {margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;text-align: justify;}

#slitp p a {font-weight: bold;color: #000099;}

 </style> 

<div id="slitp">

<h1>Your browser is outdated and open to serious security issues!</h1>You are using the long outdated Internet Explorer 6 browser. This site may not display or work correctly and you are putting your data and privacy at risk. To get the most out of the web, upgrade to the<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/ie/default.mspx" title="Download the latest version of Internet Explorer for free directly from Microsoft" alt="Download the latest version of Internet Explorer for free directly from Microsoft" "target="_blank"> new version of Internet Explorer</a> right now. If you are at work and you see this message, talk to your IT department and ask them to upgrade the browser to secure your company data. <p><a title="Stop Living In the Past" href="http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com" target="_blank">Click here to learn more about why you should upgrade your browser.</a></p>

</div>

<![endif]-->



<!-- END STOP LIVING IN THE PAST SCRIPT -->

<div id="pagewrapper">      

    <div id="wrapper">      

         <div id="innerwrap">

    <!-- /Header Starts -->      

            <div id="header">   

    <!-- /Logo Starts -->

                 <div id="headermiddlewrap">

                    <div id="logowrap">

                        <div class="logo"><img src="templates/jxtc_escene/images/<?php echo $this->params->get('eslogo'); ?>" />

                        <div class="tagtext"><?php echo $this->params->get('tagLine'); ?></div></div>

                    </div>

                 <!-- /Menu Starts -->

                    <div id="topwrap">

                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />

                    </div>

                    <div id="newsflash">

                      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="newsflash" />

                    </div>

                <!-- /Menu Ends-->

                </div>               

    <!-- /Logo Ends-->

    <!-- /TopHeader Starts -->

                    <div id="headertopwrap">

                     <div id="menuwrap">

                          <div id="topmenu">

                         <?php echo $mainmenu;?>    

                         </div>  

                    </div>  





        <!-- /search Ends-->

                         <div id="logwrap"> <a id="login_link" href="#"><?=$this->params->get('logintitle');?></a></div>

        <!-- /loginbutton Ends-->                                                                               

                    </div>



    <!-- /TopHeader Ends-->

    <!-- /Login Panel Starts -->

         <div id="memberarea" style="overflow: hidden; display: block; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; height: 0px;">

    <div id="loginwrap"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" style="panel" /></div>

  </div> 

</div>

    <!-- /Login Panel Ends -->

            <!-- INset Starts -->

                <?php if($this->countModules('inset or debug')) : ?>

                    <div id="inset">

                    <?php if($this->countModules('debug')) : ?>

                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('inset')) : ?>

                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="inset" style="xhtml" />                          

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>                      

                <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- /INset --> 

    <!-- /Content Starts -->

            <div id="content">          

            <div id="topcontent<?php echo $topdivid; ?>">

                    <div id="topcurve">

                        <div id="breadcrumbs">

                            <?php if($this->countModules('breadcrumbs')) : ?>

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumbs" style="titlewrap" />                        

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>

                        <div id="searchwrap">

                            <?php if($this->countModules('search')) : ?>

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="titlewrap"/>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>

            <!-- MainContent Starts -->

                <div id="maincontent">          

                    <?php if($this->countModules('banner')) : ?>

                        <div id="banner">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="xhtml" />                     

                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>                 

                    <?php if((JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) != '') or (JRequest::getCmd( 'option' ) != '')) :?>

                            <!-- component Starts -->

                            <?php if(JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) == 'frontpage' && $enable_frontpage=="true") :?>

                                <div id="mainbody" class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>">

                                    <jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml"  />

                                </div>

                                <div class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>-bottom"></div>

                            <!-- /MainBody -->

                            <?php elseif(JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) != 'frontpage' && JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) !='') :?>

                                <div id="mainbody" class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>">

                                    <jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml"  />

                                </div>

                                <div class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>-bottom"></div>

                            <!-- /MainBody -->

                            <?php elseif(JRequest::getCmd('option') != '' && JRequest::getCmd( 'view' ) != 'frontpage') :?>

                                <div id="mainbody" class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>">

                                    <jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml"  />

                                </div>

                                <div class="mainbody-<?php echo $this->params->get('componentstyle'); ?>-bottom"></div>

                            <!-- /MainBody -->

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <!-- /component Ends -->                    

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($this->countModules( 'user2 or user2a or user2b or user3' )) : ?>

                    <div id="topusermodsout<?php echo $topuserdivid; ?>">

                    <div id="topusermods">                                              

                        <?php if($this->countModules('user2 or user2a or user2b')) : ?> 

                            <div id="userwrap<?php echo $userwrapdivid; ?>">

                                <?php if($this->countModules('user2')) : ?> 

                                    <div id="user2">

                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="wrap" /> 

                                    </div>

                                <!-- /User1 -->

                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="moduletablewrap">

                                   <div class="moduletable-<?php echo $this->params->get('user2style'); ?>">                               

                                <?php if($this->countModules('user2a')) : ?>    

                                    <div id="user2a">

                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2a" style="wrap" /> 

                                    </div>

                                <!-- /User1 -->

                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if($this->countModules('user2b')) : ?>    

                                    <div id="user2b">

                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2b" style="wrap" /> 

                                    </div>

                                <!-- /User1 -->




                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
 <?php if($this->countModules('user2a or user2b')) : ?>                                
<div class="moduletable<?php echo "-".$this->params->get('user2style'); ?>-bottom"/></div>
    <?php endif; ?>                             

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        <!-- /User1 -->

                        <?php endif; ?>                     

                        <?php if($this->countModules('user3')) : ?>

                            <div id="user3">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="wrap" />

                            </div>

                        <!-- /USer2 -->

                        <?php endif; ?>

                   </div>

                   <!-- /Top UserMods -->

                   </div>

                   <?php endif; ?>                              





                </div>

                <!-- Right -->

                <?php if ($this->countModules( 'user1 or user4' )) : ?>

                    <div id="rightusermods">                                    

                        <?php if($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>

                            <div id="user1">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="wrap"/>

                            </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($this->countModules('user4')) : ?>

                            <div id="user4">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" style="wrap"/>

                            </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>                     

                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <!-- /Right -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>          



            <?php if($this->countModules( 'user5 or user6 or user7 or right' )) :?>

                <div id="bottomwrap<?php echo $bottomdivid; ?>">

                    <?php if($this->countModules( 'user6 or user7' )) :?>

                    <div id="bottomleftwrap<?php echo $duodivid; ?>">                                   



                            <?php if ($this->countModules( 'user6 or user7' )) : ?>

                            <div id="leftduomods">

                                <?php if($this->countModules('user6')) : ?> 

                                    <div id="user6">

                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="wrap" /> 

                                    </div>

                                <!-- /User1 -->

                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if($this->countModules('user7')) : ?>

                                    <div id="user7">

                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user7" style="wrap" />

                                    </div>

                                <!-- /USer2 -->

                                <?php endif; ?>

                           </div>

                           <!-- /Top UserMods -->

                           <?php endif; ?> 

                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?> 

                    <?php if($this->countModules( 'user5 or right' )) :?>

                    <div id="bottomrightwrap">

                        <?php if($this->countModules('user5')) : ?>

                            <div id="user5">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="wrap" />

                            </div>

                        <!-- /user5 -->

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>

                            <div id="rightcontent">

                            <div class="moduletablewrap">

                               <div class="moduletable-<?php echo $this->params->get('rightstyle'); ?>">                

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="wrap" />

                                </div>

                                <div class="moduletable<?php echo "-".$this->params->get('rightstyle'); ?>-bottom"/></div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        <!-- /user5 -->

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?> 

            </div>

            <?php endif; ?> 



        </div>

    <!-- /Content Ends-->

        </div>                  

    <!-- /InnerWrap -->    

    </div>

    </div>

    <?php if ($this->countModules( 'user8 or user9' )) : ?>          

            <div id="bottomcontent" style="background-color:<?php echo $this->params->get('bottommodstyle'); ?>">

                <div id="bottomusermodsout<?php echo $bottomuserdivid; ?>">

                <div id="bottomusermods">

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user8')) : ?>

                    <div id="user8">

                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user8" style="wrap"/>

                    </div>

                    <!-- /user5 -->

                    <?php endif; ?> 

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user9')) : ?>

                    <div id="user9">

                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user9" style="wrap"/>

                    </div>

                    <!-- /user6 -->

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>  

                </div>  

            </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

         <div id="footerwrap" style="background-color:<?php echo $this->params->get('footermodstyle'); ?>">



              <?php if ($this->countModules( 'user10 or user11 or user12 or user13 or user14' )) : ?>

                                     <div id="footermods">                                        

                                          <?php if($this->countModules('user10')) : ?>

                                          <div id="user10">

                                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user10" style="splittitle"/>

                                         </div>

    <!-- /user10 -->

                                        <?php endif; ?>   

                                          <?php if($this->countModules('user11')) : ?>

                                        <div id="user11">

                                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user11" style="splittitle"/>

                                         </div>

    <!-- /user11-->

                                          <?php endif; ?>

                                           <?php if($this->countModules('user12')) : ?>

                                           <div id="user12">

                                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user12" style="splittitle"/>

                                         </div>

    <!-- /user12-->

                                          <?php endif; ?> 

                                             <?php if($this->countModules('user13')) : ?>

                                              <div id="user13">

                                             <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user13" style="splittitle"/>

                                              </div>

    <!-- /user13-->

                                          <?php endif; ?> 

                                           <?php if($this->countModules('user14')) : ?>

                                            <div id="user14">

                                             <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user14" style="splittitle"/>

                                              </div>

    <!-- /user14-->

                                          <?php endif; ?> 

    <!-- /UserMods --></div>

                                  <?php endif; ?>



    <!-- /Footer -->

    </div>

    <!-- /FooterWrap -->                    

 <?php if($this->countModules('footer or legals')) : ?>

    <div id="bottomfoot">

    <div class="bottomfootinner">

                                    <?php if($this->countModules('footer')) : ?>

                                    <div class="foot">

                                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer"/>

    <!-- /Footer-->

                                    </div>      

                                    <?php endif; ?> 

                                           <?php if($this->countModules('legals')) : ?>

                                            <div class="legal">

                                         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="legals"/>

                                    <!-- /Legals--></div>

                                    <?php endif; ?> 

    </div>

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-6465367-6");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i guess his "error" is that the php isn’t  parsed

Comment: in ie6 and ie7 am getting that error after loading 80 % of page

Comment: Please state what error you see. Make sure that you turn off the option “display friendly HTTP errors” in IE's advanced settings, otherwise you won't see any debug output from your web server.

Comment: my site is www.musicking.in/telugu

Comment: would probably make sense if you described the resulting error a little more in depth. It's hard to look over some code if you don't know what kind of failure you're out looking for...

Comment: internet explorer cannot open the internet site www.musicking.in/telugu. operation denied this is teh error am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about “Operation Aborted”? That's the error I get.

In IE you can't alter the DOM of an element you are in the process of loading. [KB927917](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/927917) will tell you all about it. It often happens when a script that is intended to be called after page load is called inline in a script element, and tries to append to document.body. This can be unreliable and timing-specific, which makes it difficult to test locally.

I can't immediately see which script is doing that, and there are lots to go through! So try removing the scripts and adding them back one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to open this site locally? have you tried opening it in other browsers?

i suspect you’re trying to open a php script directly in a browser, which will result in the php being output but not parsed.

install an [apache](http://apachefriends.org)-server and open the file via http://localhost/yourfile.php

Comment: internet explorer cannot open the internet site 
www.musicking.in/telugu. 
operation denied

this is teh error am getting

Comment: browsing your site in firefox works without problems. is this a permament thing or did this happen only once?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php?browser=ie7&url=http://www.musicking.in/telugu/) is what the page looks like in ie7 (via ienetrenderer). Seems to be working